# Mysql select combine data of one table with two joined table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:
first main table is named as `person`

`id | name| f_name`

`-----------------`

`1  |john| mike  |`

and the second table named as `person_phone`

`p_id | phone_number |`

`1    |32423423432   |`

`1    |65743543433   |`

and the third table named as `person_address`

`p_id | address   |`

`1    |adress1|`

`1    |address2|`

now the result i want to get is

`id  |name|phone_number|address`

`1   |john|32423423432 |address1`

`1   |john|65743543433 |address2`

Answer (score 1):

The desired results give me the impression that the phone numbers are related to an address, rather than to a person.

In order to have the first phone number linked to the first addres and the second phone number to the second address reliably, you need an extra foreign key on either person_phone to refer to the key to person_address or the other way around.

If you choose person_phone to have the foreign key, that table would be like

```
p_id | address | a_id
1 |adress1| 1
1 |address2| 2
```

and person_address would need a primairy key and it would be like

```
id | p_id | address |
1 | 1 |adress1|
2 | 1 |address2|
```

your query would then be like

```
select p.id, p.name, ph.phone_number, pa.address   
left join person_address pa on pa.p_id = p.id
left join person_phone ph on ph.a_id = pa.id
```

Notice also that p_id on person_phone becomes obsolete/redundant/meaningless/confusing. The pone number will not be related to a person directly anymore, but only indirectly (but not less reliable) through the address.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id, p.name, ph.phone_number, pa.address   
from person p
left join person_phone ph on ph.p_id = p.id
left join person_address pa on pa.p_id = p.id
```